# AnsiString и функции

Tags: c++builder, c++

День добрый, ребят!
Пробую написать функцию в Билдере, которая будет возвращать переменную типа AnsiString, после чего эту переменную нужно вывести на форму.
Выводится всё нормально только в том случае, если в возвращённой переменной ОДИН символ. Если больше одного, то возвращаются цифры.
В чём соль?

Comment: Код покажите.

Comment: AnsiString testfunction ()  
{  
        AnsiString q;  
        q='q';  
        return q;  
};

Comment: @Jamko Как вы понимаете, нас интересует случай, когда у вас "возвращаются цифры". У меня есть подозрение, что вы используете одинарные кавычки вместо двойных, но я не уверен на 100%.

Comment: Действительно! Дело было в кавычках! Премного благодарен за подсказку